# What does "externalising a url" mean? (with respect to web application programming.)

Tags: web-services, web-applications

What does "externalising a url" mean? 
(with respect to web application programming.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, if you change things in your code, you have to compile, test, and deploy before you can see the changes.  To externalize is to put this information in a place where it can be changed without recompiling and reinstalling (sometimes without restarting the server/application).

Typically, you make a text file or xml somewhere and read that file in your code.  Whenever I do this, I write a service to do it for me.  That way, the same service can be reused by other parts of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be moving the url to an extarnal source. foreign to your webpage? I can't sware on it but its what comes to mind after reading your question.